# MySQL: Two of every set

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have table "Department" (200 row) & "Employees" (300,000 row) each has their own details
And the vector table combining both is "dep_emp"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dep_emp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dep_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My question is how to make a query to get two of employees (any two employees) for every Department?
My solution so far is this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `dep_emp` WHERE dep_id=1 LIMIT 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `dep_emp` WHERE dep_id=2 LIMIT 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `dep_emp` WHERE dep_id=3 LIMIT 2) ........etc
```

of course this is done {n} times for each Dept so if I wanted to display two Employees for all dept then I will have to write 199 UNION ALL, this is very ugly
Any other solutions
PS. there are a lot of details that I have moved out of the problem to make things a lot simpler

Comment: Try looking at 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643314/mysql-group-by-limit][1]
seems like the same issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643314/mysql-group-by-limit

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Department
JOIN dep_emp USING (dep_id)
JOIN Employees USING (emp_id)
WHERE emp_id IN
  (SELECT emp_id
     FROM Employees
     JOIN dep_emp USING (emp_id)
    WHERE dep_emp.dep_id = Department.dep_id LIMIT 2)
```

I didn't test it though.

OK, that didn't work. Try this instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Department
JOIN dep_emp USING (dep_id)
JOIN Employees USING (emp_id)
JOIN (SELECT emp_id, dep_id
        FROM dep_emp
    GROUP BY dep_id
       LIMIT 2) emp_2
  USING (emp_id, dep_id)
```

BTW don't forget to put some indexes on the tables. On dep_emp put a primary key on both columns AND a unique key on the columns in the reverse order! (That way the index works either way.) (You don't need the ID column in dep_emp BTW, at least not in the structure you showed.)

Comment: the last line would give an error, there is no "Department in subquery Unknown column 'Department.dep_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @bhefny Did you actually try it and are reporting the error? Because MySQL does support dependent subqueries, which is what this is. The subquery looks to the parent query to find the table Department.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually reporting the error I'm getting after testing. this is the my data:
    * MySQL client version: 5.1.49
    * PHP extension: mysqli
    * Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)

Comment: @bhefny Try the new query I put in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.*, e.* 
FROM Department AS d
  JOIN Employees AS e 
    ON e.id IN
         ( SELECT de.emp_id
           FROM dep_emp AS de
           WHERE de.dep_id = d.id
           LIMIT 2
         )
```

Another, very different way to get two `emp_id` for every department:

```
SELECT dep_id
     , MIN(emp_id) AS emp_id_1
     , MAX(emp_id) AS emp_id_2
FROM dep_emp
GROUP BY dep_id
```

or (to have in separate rows, so this can be joined to the other 2 tables):

```
    SELECT dep_id
         , MIN(emp_id) AS emp_id
    FROM dep_emp
    GROUP BY dep_id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT dep_id
         , MAX(emp_id)
    FROM dep_emp
    GROUP BY dep_id
```

---

The first query does not work in MySQL, because `LIMIT` is not allowed inside `IN` subqueries. Here's another approach:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT dep_id
      FROM  dep_emp
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    dep_emp AS e
      ON  d.dep_id = e.dep_id
      AND e.emp_id <=
          COALESCE( ( SELECT de.emp_id
                      FROM dep_emp AS de
                      WHERE de.dep_id = d.dep_id
                      ORDER BY de.emp_id         --- OFFSET 1
                      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1           --- to get 2 employess
                    )                            --- per department
                  , 9999999 )
ORDER BY e.dep_id
       , e.emp_id
```

Use `OFFSET x` to get `x+1` employees per department.

Comment: Unknown column 'd.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: The Max Min solution is limited incase I wanted 3 of every row