# PHP facebook-like inline comments under multiple posts

Tags: php, mysql

With PHP & MYSQL, I need a scalable way to show a few comments for each post just like in facebook. For all the posts in my application I need to print the most recent comments beneath the post. The problem is that I dont want to put a SQL query in a loop and have to run 20 SQL queries per page. Is there one SQL query that I can use to get the 2 most recent comments for each post that I get from the posts table.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788099/mysql-two-of-every-set

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can retrieve all the comments using one query and then store them in an array. You can then iterate over the array to organize them.